# How to specify certificate, key and root certificate with httr for certificate based authentication?

Tags: r, client-certificates, rcurl, httr

I am trying to access data using httr library from server which expects certificate based authentication. I have certificate (cert.pem), key file (key.pem) and root certificate (caroot.pem)

Following curl works.

> curl -H "userName:sriharsha@rpc.com" --cert cert.pem --key certkey.key --cacert caroot.pem https://api.somedomain.com/api/v1/timeseries/klog?limit=1

How can specify certkey.key and caroot.pem to httr GET request. I am trying with following R command but couldn't find option to specify cert key and caroot.

> cafile=????
>   r<-GET("https://api.somedomain.com/api/v1/timeseries/klog", query = list(limit = 1), add_headers("userName"= "sriharsha@rpc.com"), config(cainfo = cafile, ssl_verifypeer=FALSE), verbose())

Thus I am looking for equivalent options of httr for (--cert, --key and --cacert) of curl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [curl docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/easy_setopt_options.html), option for

1. ssl certificate is [sslcert](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLCERT.html)
2. ssl key is [sslkey](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLKEY.html)
3. ssl ca is [cainfo](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html)

As per that following command worked

> cafile="ca.pem"
>
> certfile="cert.pem"
>
> keyfile="certkey.key"
>
> r<-GET("https://api.somedomain.com/api/v1/timeseries/klog", query = list(limit = 1), add_headers("userName"= "sriharsha@rpc.com"), config(cainfo = cafile, sslcert = certfile, sslkey = keyfile))

Comment: in particular, the command line options `--cacert` corresponds to config option `cainfo`

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2023 the get method returns an error:

```
schannel: Failed to import cert file cert.pem, last error is 0x80092002
```

This seems to be linked to the issue introduced in curl in 7.55.1 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71496170/5956120)
In curl 8.0.1 using the certificate works again.

A workaround could be implemented in R:

```
# request via external tool curl (https://curl.se/windows/)
responseText <- system("<pathToCurl>/curl-8.0.1_6-win64-mingw/bin/curl.exe --cert cert.pem --key certkey.key https://api.somedomain.com/api/v1/timeseries/klog -sS", intern = TRUE)
responseJson <- paste(responseText, collapse = '')
```