# Using httr with encrypted SSL certificates

Tags: r, ssl, ssl-certificate, pki, httr

Very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273819/how-to-specify-certificate-key-and-root-certificate-with-httr-for-certificate-b) question. Except I would like to know how to make a GET request with httr when the private key is **encrypted**?

The following example works fine when `certkey.key` is unencrypted.

```
library(httr)    
cafile="ca.pem"
certfile="cert.pem"
keyfile="certkey.key"
r<-GET("https://www.example.com/api/timeseries&firstname=Joe", config(cainfo = cafile, sslcert = certfile, sslkey = keyfile))
```

For security reasons, I need a solution that does not require an unencrypted keyfile. When `certkey.key` is encrypted, the SSL handshake fails with the message:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :     SSL
>   connect error

I think this happens because httr does not prompt to ask for a passphrase like you would see when using the analogous curl command. It instead errors out.

Comment: prbly shld post this as an issue on the `curl` gh repo or `httr` repo

Comment: That's the plan. I wanted to ask on here first to see if there was a simple fix, like enabling some config option.